# From WPF development to ASP.NET development

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, static-libraries

I have a lot of experience developing rich WPF applications (for CRM scenarios). I am a single developer and use Visual Studio with a TFS for revision control.
I have build a Framework which automatically takes care of the most basic tasks for me. To start a new (WPF) Application project all i have to do is:

1. create a new project
2. include references to my function libraries
3. defining the data structure in an XML file
4. inherit the new application Class from my custom Application class

My libraries include functionality for

- backend creation and connection
- a Main Window with user login and administrative/configuration options
- custom controls
- custom scheduling system for background task
- etc. etc.

Every development step from that point out is specific to the current task/costumer/product. I can concentrate 100% on modeling and creating custom ui Pages for special purposes - an average project can contain as little as 100 lines of unique code. If i stumble over any reusable functionality whatsoever, i add that to my libraries. 
I can deploy and update all Projects with literally one click. This enables me to handle many projects as a single developer.

**My question is: how much of that "developing experience" can (I) translate to ASP.NET development.**

I am uncertain of this because of the mix of technologies Javascript(jQuery)/HTML/VB.NET(or C#)
I am familiar enough with each of the languages and feel able to be working effectively with Servicestack after a little learning by doing.
But my biggest concern is: will I have just as much reusability as with my WPF development setup.

My biggest, dealbreaking-if-not-met goals are:

- not ever "physically" copy any functionality - everything has to be linked from libraries
- have a reusable "Main Page Layout/Setup" with login functionality - this also has to be in a library!
- never leave Visual Studio as a Development environment

All my models/function libraries that i need to rely on (backend functionality and utility functions) are developed in .NET 2.0

Thank you very much for your input!

**Edit for clarification:**
I am not looking for the "Template" functionality of Visual Studio. I am well aware of this and using it where appropriate. This is not enough for me as changes/improvements/expansion of my libraries have to be reflected in all Projects - this also holds for the "Main/Start Page" functionality.

The built-in ASP.NET Templates from Visual Studio are actually a great example for what i do **not** want. They produce a very specific setup for your "new" application with a lot of autogenerated code - i.e. "physically copying" this code from a template to adjust to your needs.

What I want to do is every time when i start a new Project:

1. start on an "empty" ASP.NET Project
2. Create neccessary Cloud services (hosting/database/buckets) etc. in Azure (which VS incorporates very nicely)
3. include my needed libraries (that for example in turn include the neccessary servicestack libraries)
4. start modeling/designing specific needs for the new project

Comment: Couldn't you just set the template for new project in VS to whatever you want to begin with?

Comment: "template functionality" - if i understand what you mean - is not enough. Changes/improvements/expansions to my libraries have to be reflected in ALL projects, be it old or new ones.

Comment: @themightylc Not sure if this help,but you may take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx) to use the power of Scaffolding and couple it with Text Templating(T4 templates).

Comment: Just to add your best bet is silverlight. The view engine is completely different one is html and another one is xaml

Comment: Thank you for your input. The idea of using Silverlight has become very stale for me since Microsoft declared it obsolete with the dawn of WinRT and I don't like the prospect of forcing browser choices or installation of plugins on the end user. Lave alone the fact that IF i want to start developing for the web i want solutions that can be used on all devices out of the box.

Comment: Scaffolding looks very interesting. I will have a look at it.